# Accessing folders in Windows 10 from a java application in a Docker container

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, windows-10, dockerfile

Good day!

 I'm new to Docker, really need help.

 System: Windows 10, Docker Desktop

 Application: Java Spring-Boot application that transfers files in different folders of the system according to a certain logic. Wrapped in a Docker container

Problem: Java Spring-Boot application does not see folders in Windows 10 (any, for example "my documents",
"C: \ Program Files" and so on.
The application should take the file from the "C: \ Users \ Denis \ Downloads" folder and put it in the "C: \ Users \ Denis \ Documents" folder,

 but I get an error: java.lang.NullPointerException: null "folder does not exist"

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk / openjdk8
ARG JAR_FILE = target / relocator.jar
WORKDIR / opt / app
COPY $ {JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENDPOINT ["java", "- jar", "app.jar"]
```

What do I need to add to the Dockerfile and what commands to execute in the "console"? Please in more detail, because I have already spent a lot of time, but there is no result.
Thank you:)

Comment: One of the major design goals of Docker is that a program in a container can't access host files in the way you describe.  Does this program need to be in a container, or can you run it directly on the host system?

Comment: How much have you learned about how docker works?

Answer (score 0):

Application inside docker does not have access to file system outside container. In order to do so you will need to atache volume to your container.
Whole concept and how to do is described here : https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/.